# Called a component on button press which returns modal but it is not visible on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I called a component on button press to display modal on screen but it is not working properly.

```
const  handleCardClick=(cardObject)=> {
  
  this.state={
    "show":true
  }

 console.log("pressed")

return (<Modal
show={true}
onHide={() => this.setState({"show":false})}
dialogClassName="modal-90w"
aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
  <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
    Custom Modal Styling
  </Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
  <p>
    Ipsum molestiae natus adipisci modi eligendi? Debitis amet quae unde
    commodi aspernatur enim, consectetur. Cumque deleniti temporibus
    ipsam atque a dolores quisquam quisquam adipisci possimus
    laboriosam. Quibusdam facilis doloribus debitis! Sit quasi quod
    accusamus eos quod. Ab quos consequuntur eaque quo rem! Mollitia
    reiciendis porro quo magni incidunt dolore amet atque facilis ipsum
    deleniti rem!
  </p>
</Modal.Body>
</Modal>
);
}
```

"pressed" is displayed but I can't see modal on screen.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which third party component are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look much like a standard react component IMO, but I guess you won't need a function to display the component. The  component should be present in your render method and it's "open" property is what makes it to be displayed or not.

Also, you have not specified which library you are using, but "show" doesn't sound familiar to me. MUI for instance has it as "isOpen={modalOpen}". Anyway I hope the snippet bellow can help.

```
class MyButtonModalComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {
        modalOpen: false
    }

    render(){

        const { modalOpen } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={e=>this.setState({ modalOpen: true })}>Click here to open a modal window</Button>
                <Modal
                    show={modalOpen}
                    onHide={() => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                    >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
                            Custom Modal Styling
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>Ipsum ... </p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: handleCardClick  is one of the component which is called on a button click and when I click the button it must return a modal.